# Python How to loop through each row and see if condition is met between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns. I want to update the third column, `status`, if the first column, `a` is greater than or equal to column `b` + 0.50. I've tried this following code but cannot get it to work:

```
if df['a'] >= (df['b'] + 0.50):
    df['status'] = 1
```

`status` is already populated with zeros.

how would i go about this?

Comment: Pandas can do a lot of the work for you. `df.loc[df['a'] >= df['b']+0.50, 'status'] = 1`

Comment: Keep in mind that code like `(df['b'] + 0.50)` will operate on *the entire column at once*. It creates a *new column* with all the modified values. Similarly with comparisons between two columns. A column cannot be used for an `if` check; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951 . But even then, `df['status'] = 1` sets *the entire column at once*. To write good Pandas code, it is necessary to understand this kind of "broadcasting" or "vectorization". You may find it useful to practice with Numpy first.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `np.where`

```
df['status'] = np.where(df['a'] >= (df['b'] + 0.50),1,0)
```

Or just

```
df['status'] = (df['a'] >= (df['b'] + 0.50)).astype(int)
```

Or `loc`

```
df.loc[(df['a'] >= (df['b'] + 0.50)),'status'] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  lambda function :

```
def myFunc(x): 
    if(x[0]>=x[1]+0.50) :
        return 1
    else: return x[2]

df['status'] = df.apply(lambda x:myFunc(x),axis=1)
```